# What's the difference between Application.Contents and Application.StaticObjects in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

There are two collections in the [`Application` object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_application.asp) in Classic ASP:

- `Application.StaticObjects`, filled in `<object>` sections in `global.asa`
- `Application.Contents`, filled by whatever code decides to store something there, including `<script>` sections in `global.asa`

I note one apparent disadvantage of the `StaticObjects` collection: You cannot initialize objects you store. Let's take the example of an XML document. You can store a free-threaded DOM object there, but how if you wanted to preload an XML file? I cannot see a way to achieve this.

Does `StaticObjects` have any advantage to compensate for this disadvantage?

More generally, how are these collections different with regard to things like concurrency or access or whatnot?

---

The discussion below has shown that there actually is an advantage to using `<object>` and hence `Application.StaticObjects`, and that is *lazy evaluation*. But then, of course, lazy evaluation is something you can easily code yourself (and with greater flexibility) in a script. Still, for application-scoped singletons to be created on demand, the `<object>` tag can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never come across any need or advantage to use `<object>` in the Global.asa as opposed to simply using `Contents` in the `OnStart` event.

Apart from the way objects end up being instanced and placed in these collections there is no real difference betweent them.  Objects need to be free-threaded and thread-safe.

My advice would to just ignore `StaticObjects` and work with simple code.

Comment: Thanks. For my book *ASP with VBScript - The Good Parts*, due to be published mid-2012, the `StaticObjects` collection, right along with the `<object>` tag, will receive prominent placing in *Appendix U - Useless Parts*.

Comment: Okay, @Dee pointed to a [good article on MSDN titled "25+ ASP Tips to Improve Performance and Style"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx#asptips_topic18) which states that *lazy evaluation* is the feature that can justify using `<object>` in `global.asa` and hence `Application.StaticObjects`. So I'll have to revise my plans for Appendix U.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different collections.  The idea of advantage/disadvantage is not applicable.

Application Contents Collection:

The Contents collection is a group all of the items that have been added to the application through a script command.

Application StaticObjects Collection:

The StaticObjects collection contains all of the objects created with the  tags within the scope of the Application object.

Comment: Thanks, Dee. Even though the idea of advantage or disadvantage might not be applicable from the point of view of machine-like objectivity, the programmer trying to make sense of the toolset at his disposal may legitimately wonder what the heck this or that odd-looking device is for, especially when no clear application is in sight and examples are lacking. When not yet experienced with a  toolset, I tend to give it a lot of credit, thinking that the inventors wouldn't have included even the oddest-looking tool if it weren't for a very good reason.

Comment: It is there for a good reason.  Using the <object> tag is a means of improving performance, see tip 17 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx#asptips_topic18.  The StaticObjects collection contains all the objects appended to the application/session with the HTML <object> tag.

Comment: Okay, that's a [useful link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx#asptips_topic18). So the one and only selling point for `Application.StaticObjects` is **lazy evaluation**. To quote the doc: *`Server.CreateObject` creates the object immediately. If you don't use that object later, you end up wasting resources. The `<object id=objname>` tag declares `objname`, but `objname` isn't actually created until the first time that one of its methods or properties are used.*